# "Guys" losing its gendered meaning in American English

Tags: american-english, semantics, gender-neutral, semantic-shift

*Disclaimer* - I have very little knowledge of semantics, and I am mostly just a phonetics enthusiast. Thus, my question and the way I explain it may be unprofessional or may lack linguistic rigor.

I'm a teenager, and I'm from the American Midwest. One feature famously characteristic of discourse in the Midwest and central United States is the use of the phrase "you guys" as a second-person plural pronoun. As a Chicagoan, I can confirm that this phrase is indeed quite common, as opposed to the rarer "y'all" (Southern connotation) and "you all." A simple "you" is still possible.

The word "guy" of course has historically had a gendered connotation, applying specifically to males. However, I wonder if it can be reasonably claimed that the plural form "guys" and modified forms such as "you guys" and "those guys" have lost their gendered nature.

Like the masculine third-person plural pronouns in Romance languages ("Ils" for French), "you guys" can be used to refer to a mixed-gender group. I assume this is a well-established usage. However, I think the phrase has lost its gender specificity enough that the gender of the group may not even matter. I think there are many situations in which calling a group of women or girls "you guys" might be considered perfectly normal - although I don't know if everyone, especially people from other parts of the US and the Anglosphere, would agree. I think it would be only slightly less normal to refer to an exclusively female group with a phrase like "those guys."

You can also say something like "Guys, it's raining outside" to a group of women or girls. I am guessing this has something to do with "guys" being placed in the vocative case, acting almost like an interjection. However, the situation is probably a bit more nuanced and complex.

The genderlessness does not seem to extend to the singular form, "guy." In some cases, a person might default to "guy" to refer to a hypothetical person or a person whose gender is unknown, but typically the word would only refer to a male.

My uneducated analysis of this situation leads me to the tentative claim that while "guys" still has a clear gender connotation, it has essentially lost its gendered function when modified with an initial word like "you" or (slightly less so) "those" or when in the vocative case. However, it maintains genderedness in other cases or in the singular form.

I am wondering the extent to which it can be said that these terms have lost their gendered definitions in American English, and what the proper way of classifying this shift might be.

Comment: A similar development applies to _dude_ (in the singular), which is now fairly common in some dialects even in conversations with no male participants. But this question should really be asked on [english.se] instead of here, since it’s specifically about the usage of an English term and isn’t about language as a system. It can be migrated there by a moderator.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Although it is about the usage of an English term, I am trying to ask for a formal linguistic explanation of the semantic phenomenon I have described, and I am not sure that ELU is a better Stack Exchange than Linguistics for me to find that.

Comment: Well, first, Anne Curzan (Curzan 2003: 173) argues that “The shift of the prototypical meaning of *guy* to males seems to be a twentieth-century phenomenon” and then “semantic bleaching”happened in *you guys* regardless of gender or *that guy* meaning  that thing (she uses it in quotes because it could be arguable). https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/gender-shifts-in-the-history-of-english/114DB77B6E95F078C2A66FDEE978526A

Comment: You may also want to take a look at Clancy, S. J. (1999). The Ascent of Guy. American Speech, 74(3), 282–297. http://www.jstor.org/stable/455646

Comment: Curzan's explanation sounds very likely. That's the way it appeared to me as it happened.

Comment: Having fun with words: (Proto-Germanic *kuntō, (ahem): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunt#:~:text=Reflecting%20national%20variations%2C%20cunt%20can,in%20Australia%20and%20New%20Zealand. AKA "gendered vitriol".

Comment: A similar trend is seen in Dutch with the phrase *jongens*.

Comment: What do you mean, "historically"? "Guy" only meant "male" for one or two hundred years, tops? It literally comes from a guy's name, Guy Fawkes (mostly a male name, itself derived/respelled from French). The 19th and 20th centuries seem to have been particularly bent on gendering things that weren't gendered before - including such "staples" as girl, boy or even man (_woman_ was gendered, of course). Things are just coming back to "normal".

Comment: @Luaan I think you can ask a new question about the variation of usage of "historically" depending on context. Science and technology people just for example often use it just to refer to "back when I was your age" or "they use do it differently". People doing automated stock trading programs use "historical" data sets that might be pretty short as well.

Comment: Also using plural *they/their/them* instead of gendered *he/she*.

Comment: While it may *mostly* be considered non-gendered, it's still a term that's best to avoid in male-dominated groups (such as software engineering) as it can feel non-inclusive in those contexts.

Comment: You may want to at least consider the possibility that the term losing its gendered meaning is a product of long-standing male-dominated culture in the English language world (or maybe North America?) and try to get opinions from a larger number of female or otherwise "non-Male" persons. Taking a stab here and assuming that a very large portion of SE users are not female. (Wow did some research... 2014-2019 on SO....)

Comment: @RickHenderson Anecdotally, women report using "you guys" to groups of all-women. I still try to avoid it but what do I know :shrug:

Comment: Well, it's because "gals" seems clunky -- seems old-fashioned and vaguely sexist-- "girls" is also obviously problematic-- so what *else* are you going to say?  I guess you could say "hey, women" -- but who ever says "hey, men" except for a drill sergeant addressing his troops?  (Oops, I made a presumption there didn't I).  Actually, these days, it could be "Hey all you GuGOWEYPRIs!"  (Guys, gals, or what ever your preferred referential pronoun is.)  Could you just abbeviate to "Hey, thems" or "Hey, theys"?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have rep on this site to be able to answer a protected question, but this is not so much a matter of a case where it's "losing" its gendered meaning, but rather that there are simply two different definitions, one of which is gendered and one of which is not (but the second one is only used in the plural form.) [Both definitions are listed in Merriam-Webster's dictionary.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guys)

Comment: My observation (SW USA) is that words such as "guys" have come to apply to mixed-gender groups but usually not all-female groups.

Comment: Keep in mind that communication is a two-way street. While it may be possible for the speaker to use "you guys" in an intentionally gender-neutral way, the listener must always guess whether the intention (or assumption) of the speaker was gendered usage or not. I'd argue therefore that it's quite hard for 'you guys' to completely lose its gendered connotation, and that this has not happened yet.

Comment: To 'y'all/you all' a simple 'you' is never comparable.

'You' can of course be plural but it more often refers to the single person to whom you're speaking.

Neither 'y'all' nor 'you all' is ever used of a single listener; neither could ever refer to anything but a group audience, even if the group was only two strong.

Comment: @RickHenderson You might want to consider the possibility that in the long term, losing gendered meaning is a product of exactly the opposite of long-standing male-dominated culture.

Comment: When I was in high school near Louisville KY in the 60s "guys" was commonly used to refer to both genders and it hardly raised an eyebrow.

Answer (score 31):

This shift is basically old news, having been around for over 40 years. It's an example of generalization in semantics, where a property previously seen as being essential to the term is dropped in ranking. Earlier, one of the essential properties was contextual informality – it's an endearative; and it used to only refer to males. The word "folks" is similar but has the defect of lacking a singular. The current situation is that, idiolectally, there is only a weak suggestion that the referents are male. It is most likely to be used in the plural: we would need a controlled sociolinguistic study to see whether it is used to refer to a singular non-male.

The larger point is that there are essentials and non-essentials in word definitions. For example, the noun "press" originally was a device for pushing down on a thing, including pushing a bed of inked metal type onto paper. The method used to print newspapers and books is not really essential to the concept of "the press" as enshrined in the First Amendment, so what was one part of the definition of "press" in the publishing sense was eliminated entirely as non-essential.

I think it is a mistake to try to "classify" such changes, instead, one ought to try to understand what the changes are, and see if there is a good reason to distinguish this kind of semantic change from another kind of semantic change.

Comment: Re: _press_. I've always been amused that the Italian word with the same connotation and much the same usage is _stampa_, from another "press" verb that's gone through the same technological tunnel. Similar remarks on football "net" versus "web/reti". You take a word you're used to and you make it work harder in another context.

Comment: I think "dude" is the male singular of "guys".

Comment: @Nelson If you ask a straight man if he has had sex with any "guys" or "dudes", I bet he will answer emphatically no.

Comment: Why would it be a "defect" that _folks_ lacks a singular?

Comment: @EllenSpertus sex is particularly concerned with gender, so the use of "guys" when talking about sex would imply that their gender matters. In other content, "guys" can refer to ladies, like "Come here you guys!" But then when referring to specific groups of people, like "Those guys." then gender matters again.

Hmm, English is just messed up actually.

Comment: @Schmuddi: This is just linguistic terminology: We call an inflection paradigm *defective* when it lacks some possible members. It goes back to Latin grammar, where paradigms like *vis, vim, vi* (for a noun) or *inquit* (for a verb) are examples.

Comment: A common phrase in American movies is "I know a guy". It is said when someone has a problem to deal with, and someone "knows a guy" who can deal with these kinds of problems (usually by providing an illegal service). I'm sure there are example of movies where the "guy" in question is a woman.

Comment: But "folks" has always been genderless, hasn't it?  Or if it used to refer only to males, it made the switch to being genderless long before "guys" did at least.

Comment: @SirCornflakes: Thanks for the hint. I know about defective paradigms, but it didn't click with me to think of that when reading about "the defect" as a noun.

Comment: @Stef But I'm also sure there's instances where someone says "I know a guy" and the next scene has the "guy" being a women for comedic effect....which is only funny if "guy" implies male.

Comment: @EllenSpertus This is a well-worn gotcha but I don't think it is relevant.  "Guys" used in vocative form, as in "take a look at this, guys," is frequently used in all-female groups, which cannot be said of "men" ("take a look at this, men" definitely implies all-male listenership), so it's different.

Comment: I don't think *folks* lacks a singular... rather it is another example where the meaning has shifted, so *folks* is not anymore synonymous to  *nations* or *peoples*

Comment: Off topic, but I knew a couple in the 1970s who had a 4-year-old called Guy who got really upset around November 5th. UK locale.

Comment: @EllenSpertus That's because there are two different definitions for the word "guys." One is gendered and other isn't. The context in your suggested sentence implies the gendered one, while lots of other contexts imply the non-gendered one. Basically, if the context doesn't have anything to do with gender, then the non-gendered definition is generally assumed. [Merriam-Webster's lists both definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guys), but (correctly) notes that the second is only used in the plural form.

Comment: "Over 40 years"? My wife was at university in the UK in the early 1970s and was surprised by a friend addressing a group of girls as "you guys". The friend, for context, was from California and black. It was a usage you would not have normally encountered in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelKay -this is my (UK) experience too (that it was initially perceived as an Americanism). As late as the last decade I have been irritated by senior British managers in my organisation coming down from London to address us and saying 'you guys'.

Comment: I'm a Brit in the north of England, and I've noticed [*without* irritation] servers in bars and restaurants using 'You guys'.  But I realized how common that usage had become when my mother died: sitting in the funeral home making plans for her funeral, the young director addressed my sister [aged 70] and me [aged 73] as 'You guys'.

Answer (score 6):

I agree that "you guys" is non-gendered in modern English. And possibly also "hey guys," to a much lesser extent. But I still think the word "guy" is gendered in pretty much every other context. For example I wouldn't say the following to refer to a group with any women in it, and I'm surprised other respondents here would:

- "those guys"
- "I know a guy"

If I heard someone refer to a group of women as "those guys" I would think it was strange. Keep in mind also that "guy" is not only gendered, but in some contexts it is even the default way to refer to a male in a casual sense. For example let's say I'm asking a friend if there will be both men and women present at a social event. I might say "will there be guys and girls there?" I probably wouldn't say "men and women" (and definitely not "males and females") since it would sound too formal.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but rather a longish comment.

Comment: Are you sure? While it's hard to definitely say what the original question was – there were no question marks at all in the post – it seems to me it was essentially _"I am wondering the extent to which it can be said that these terms have lost their gendered definitions in American English"_. So I am clarifying that the term hasn't lost its gendered meaning to the extent OP may think. And in fact it may be more gendered than he realizes.

Comment: @Anonymous you make an excellent point! :-) +1

Comment: I find it interesting that we can ask "will there be guys and girls there?" and the contrasting feminist request that "girls" be used only for children and not adult women. Is there a modern, non-awkward way to ask this question without using "girls"? The best I can come up with is "will there be dudes and chicks there?", which is not only cringe but probably also objectionable to feminists. "Will there be boys and girls there" is clearly about children only, and "men and women there?" is just awkward.

Comment: If you try to worry about pleasing niche groups with your language, you're going to have a bad time. Even if you found the right way to refer to men and women at the party, the question would still be exclusionary of transpeople. Best off to just use the language that sounds right to you and that most people would understand what you're asking.

Comment: @nerdfever.com "will there be both men and women there?" doesn't sound awkward to me.

Comment: @nerdfever.com "Gal" used to be the female equivalent of "guy", but for whatever reason it fell out of usage. "Girl" seems to have crept into the gap left by it.

Comment: @Cruncher it would exclude non binary people, not trans people. If I ask "will there be any women there?" and it will be all men and a trans woman, the answer is "yes" because trans women are women.

Comment: @KateGregory https://www.mic.com/life/are-non-binary-people-trans "Basically, there is no single answer to the question of whether nonbinary people are trans. It is a question that can only be answered by trans and gender non-conforming (TGNC) individuals within their own respective TGNC communities." Sounds exclusionary to say that non-binaries are fullstop not trans

Comment: I didn't say that @Cruncher. If you want to say "will exclude nonbinary people" say it. Saying "will exclude trans people" implies they are (all) not included in "men" and "women".

Answer (score 1):

https://www.etymonline.com/word/guy suggests the word originates from "small rope, chain, wire" (1620s), and may have linking to the word "guide". You can imagine, I'm sure that a particular (nautical) rope having "guiding" qualities might be called a "guide rope", and since little knowledge was written, this became spoken as "guy rope" (which we still use today, on tents, for example).

The source then suggests "guy" was used to mean "fellow" in American English in 1847. Again, you can imagine how that may have come about - perhaps as a term of endearment for an acquaintance who was something of a leader (or possibly through the same mis-hearing that turned "guide" into "guy" in the first place?).

The American English usage of the word was (IMHO) most likely used to describe a man, predominantly because, at that time, most precarious activities were performed by men, whilst women tended to homely duties. Therefore, if you said "guy", it was generally understood to mean you were talking about a man, despite the word being ungendered, and perhaps more about a "guide" or a sturdy rope(?).

The word is undergoing something of a conscious ungendering, as indeed are many words or phrases, as we become more aware of patriarchy and other challenging social constructs. As noted by @user6726, this has been going on for quite some time already, but is perhaps more pronounced in recent years.

Update: Comments suggest the reference I used is unreliable. [Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy#Etymology_1) suggests the term primarily comes from Guy Fawkes, but also confirms the French "Guido" (Guide). [Word Histories](https://wordhistories.net/2016/11/04/guy/) also confirms the French origins, but again suggests Guy Fawkes. [Panlex](https://panlex.org/blog/meet-the-etymology-guy/) talks about the origins of the (male) given name "Guy", and also talked about Guy Fawkes. [Chatterbug](https://chatterbug.com/community/t/the-etymology-of-guy/903) has an entirely different take on the origins of the name.

Whatever the origins, the *name* "Guy" (for a man) seems to have appeared in England around 1066. This could of course have been the origin, subsequently "popularised" by Guy Fawkes 600-odd years later. This doesn't really shed any light on the plural "guys" though. We don't generally pluralise other names, which suggests there may be another route for that particular word through history.

Comment: Forget about etymonline: It is a one-person amateur project and consists of copycat work with sources not quoted. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy#Etymology_1) disagrees, and it has a References section.

Comment: In what way does wiktionary disagree with etymonline?

Comment: It's not that Etymonline is unreliable, it's that you've combined the etymologies of two totally unrelated words; note the headings 'guy (n. 1)' and 'guy (n. 2)'. Wiktionary also has both words; if you scroll down the page, you'll find 'Etymology 2: From Old French *guie*, linked to verb *guier* (“guide”), from Frankish **wītan*, ultimately from Proto-Germanic **wītaną* (“know”).' This agrees with Etymonline.

Comment: @SirCornflakes Etymonline may be the passion project of one person, but [the sources](https://www.etymonline.com/columns/post/sources?utm_source=etymonline_footer&utm_medium=link_exchange) they used are absolutely reliable. Are you really saying that Wiktionary, which can be edited by anybody and demonstrably contains all sorts of crap is a better resource than Etymonline? Citation very much needed. Especially since the relevant entry (for _guy_) has no References section and absolutely no references quoted.

Comment: @terdon: Last I visited etymonline, it was not given where a particular etymology there was taken from. The site only gives a list of references, many of which are reputable, but it was untraceable. Did you read the Wiktionary entry? It has references for guy (some old etymological dictionary from 1911) giving the two quoted etymologies.

Comment: @SirCornflakes no, it doesn't give where each specific one came from which is why you're not wrong that it isn't perfect. My point is that despite this, I have never found it to be wrong (granted, this could just be my own ignorance) while I have often found crappy stuff on Wiktionary and that is expected given its model. So had you suggested pretty much anything other than Wiktionary I would have understood but etymonline is by far the best and most reliable English etymology resource that is freely available on the web in my experience. I can't find the references you mention on Wiktionary.

Comment: In any case, in this instance [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guy#Etymology_1) and [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/guy#etymonline_v_14401) agree on the etymology and both link the word _guy_ to Guy Fawkes so I guess the point is moot. I just found it very surprising that anyone would recommend a site that has no restrictions and allows random anonymous users to edit it (Wiktionary) as a reliable resource. And I now found the references and yes, it points to [here](http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/cent2jpgframes.php?volno=03&page=2663), fair enough.

Comment: @RalphBolton To clear up confusion, some comments on the updated answer: 1. 'Wiktionary suggests the term primarily comes from Guy Fawkes, but also confirms the French "Guido" (Guide).' The first half of your sentence is correct. However, Wiktionary does not say that Guy is from French 'Guido', and 'Guido' certainly does not mean guide! You might again be confounding this 'guy' with the other 'guy' (a guide cable). Guy is a common name in French; it's the same name as Guido in Italian. It was (and still is) a much less common name in English, which  probably helped the meaning to transform.

Comment: 2. 'Word Histories also confirms the French origins, but again suggests Guy Fawkes.' The way you write this suggests that there is a conflict here when there is none. Guy Fawkes is the origin of 'guy', and the name Guy is of French origin. 3. 'Chatterbug has an entirely different take on the origins of the name.' Does it? As far as I can see, this site gives the same origin, namely Guy Fawkes. What do you see that's entirely different?

Comment: 4. 'Whatever the origins, the name "Guy" (for a man) seems to have appeared in England around 1066.' Given the French origins, it would make sense that the name was introduced following the Norman Conquest. Hundreds of years later, Guy Fawkes attempted to blow up the parliament; shortly after, a 'guy' meant an effigy of Fawkes, and then just 'man'. So, 5. 'This doesn't really shed any light on the plural "guys" though.' If the singular means 'man', then the plural means 'men'. There's nothing strange going on here.